# HP Pavilion p7-1235 Windows works but Ubuntu turns off

Tags: 12.04, hp

I've just done a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP P7-1235 which runs windows 7 just fine. Every time I try running Ubuntu it randomly shuts off. No freezing, no overheating...my screen goes blank and then nothing.

I've installed the Desktop version, the Server version and ran it from the Live CD and each time I have the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IF you can get it to boot, **hit the little icon just to the top right of your login** and change the option to **"Ubuntu 2D"**

Another thing you can try is to go into the **"Screen Lock" settings**, find it by typing it into the start search -> **set "turn my monitor off after" to "never"**

It could be a power management incompatibility because its an APU... and frankly ive not played with those yet.

But because its a cpu+VGA it seems to me it might have something funky with the screen sleep.

To solve that long term will take someone more clever than me, but then... i might even be wrong with this.